# JavaScript to save MAFF in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, archive, save-as

I am experimenting with iMacros to automate as task that Firefox will do. I simply want to save the current page with the MAFF extension. The JavaScript that the iMacros forum has lead me to, is this:

```
// I stuck these variable in just to try something.
var doc = "http://www.traderjoes.com";
var file = "C:\\Export\\Test.maff";
var format = "MAFF";
// I stuck these variable in just to try something.

var MafObjects = {};
Components.utils.import("resource://maf/modules/mafObjects.jsm",
                        MafObjects);
var jobListener = {
  onJobComplete: function(aJob, aResult) {
    if (!Components.isSuccessCode(aResult)) {
      // An error occurred
    } else {
      // The save operation completed successfully
    }
  },
  onJobProgressChange: function(aJob, aWebProgress, aRequest,
                                aCurSelfProgress,
                                aMaxSelfProgress,
                                aCurTotalProgress,
                                aMaxTotalProgress) { },
  onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus,
                           aMessage) { }
};
var saveJob = new MafObjects.SaveJob(jobListener);
saveJob.addJobFromDocument(doc, file, format);
saveJob.start();
```

I was only getting an error on line 26 because this was sample code. With the little JavaScript I know I tried to add some variables on the lines before the code starts. The thing is that when I try to search for syntax example for the method .addJobFromDocument I don’t find much, just like two results. Is this a method of JavaScript? Usually with things from the DOM you will get a great deal of information on them.

Does anybody know a way of automating the save of MAFF of the current open tab in Firefox and then closing the browser? iMacros was something I came to and glad to see it features but really I just want to automate from a command line the saving of a URL as a MAFF archive The doc (that I got from iMacros forum) also had these code snippets but I don’t have much idea how to use them. Thanks

```
var fileUri = Components.
              classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].
              getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService).
              newFileURI(file);
var persistObject = new MafObjects.MafArchivePersist(null, format);
persistObject.saveDocument(doc, fileUri);
```

Also:

```
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
           createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\My Documents\\Test.maff");
var format = "TypeMAFF";
```